# problem with sql server compact 3.5 and smart device project

Tags: c#, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

Recently i downloaded SQLServer Compact 3.5 from Microsoft web site, and i have already installed Visual Studio 2008.
When i make a new Smart Device project and try to connect some Dataset to local database, the following error rises :
"Error  1   Custom tool error: This operation requires a reference to SQL Server Compact 3.5. The project has a reference to a different version. Update the reference and try again."

i tried reinstalling  Visual Studio 2008, but it did not work.

Comment: Which version did you have a reference to?

Comment: Have you installed Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack?

Comment: i referenced to ver 3.5 , and i did not installed service pack.there was not any problem until i get new version of SQL Server ce from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem, This problem is happen with SQL Compact service pack2, but you can use SP1 and use code to manipulate your database. It had been solved.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after update SQL server compact 3.5 to SP2.

The solution is to uninstall SP2 and install version without Service Pack and re-add the reference to SQL CE in project

Comment: at the moment I cant check your solution, but thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the existing project reference to SQL CE, close the project, re-open the project and re-add the reference.